Why does my Django ORM query with naive datetimes return the same results as a PostgreSQL query with time zone-aware datetimes?
I'm using Django to filter reservations based on a date range with naive datetimes. My Django ORM query is:
start_d_date_naive = "2024-11-3 00:00"
end_d_date_naive = "2024-11-3 23:59"
reserve_naive = Reservations.objects.filter(
    updated_at__range=(start_d_date_naive, end_d_date_naive), status="canceled"
)

This translates to the following SQL query:
SELECT * FROM "consultant_reservations"
WHERE "consultant_reservations"."status" = 'canceled'
AND "consultant_reservations"."updated_at" BETWEEN '2024-11-03 00:00:00' AND '2024-11-03 23:59:00'

However, the results are the same as if I had run this query directly in PostgreSQL:
SELECT * FROM "consultant_reservations"
WHERE updated_at BETWEEN '2024-11-03 00:00:00+03:30' AND '2024-11-03 23:59:00+03:30'
AND status='canceled';

Why does the Django ORM query with naive datetimes return the same results as the PostgreSQL query with time zone-aware datetimes?

settings.py contains:
TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Tehran'

USE_TZ = False

Testing in Django shell:
In [14]: from django.conf import settings

In [15]: print(settings.TIME_ZONE)
Asia/Tehran

The PostgreSQL server:
=> SHOW timezone;
 TimeZone 
----------
 Etc/UTC
(1 row)

Server's containing Django project which is Ubuntu server:
$ timedatectl
               Local time: Tue 2024-11-05 12:25:58 UTC
           Universal time: Tue 2024-11-05 12:25:58 UTC
                 RTC time: Tue 2024-11-05 12:25:58
                Time zone: Etc/UTC (UTC, +0000)
System clock synchronized: yes
              NTP service: active
          RTC in local TZ: no



What version of Django? 2) Where are you setting TIME_ZONE, for the overall installation or in the DATABASE settings?


Also what is the data type for the field updated_at?

python -m django --version 4.0

settings.py contains:
TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Tehran'
USE_TZ = False
Testing in Django shell:
In [14]: from django.conf import settings
In [15]: print(settings.TIME_ZONE)
Asia/Tehran
The PostgreSQL server:
=> SHOW timezone;
` TimeZone
Etc/UTC
(1 row)`
These have is there with better typing format in rest question above.

In Django models:
updated_at        = models.DateTimeField()
In psql terminal:
=> \d consultant_reservations
updated_at        | timestamp with time zone |           | not null |


Add the new information above to the question text.  2) Django 4.0 is ~1.50 past EOL, you should look at upgrading to at least 4.2 LTS.  I am still trying to figure out what you are seeing.


With Postgres server timezone='UTC':  1) select  '2024-11-03 00:00:00'::timestamp at time zone 'Asia/Tehran'  at time zone 'UTC'; 2024-11-02 20:30:00  2) select  '2024-11-03 00:00:00+03:30'::timestamptz  at time zone 'UTC'; 2024-11-02 20:30:00. Where 1) is what is happening in the Django query and 2) Is what is happening in the Postgres direct query.

@AdrianKlaver, You means that In Django query, (which USE_TZ = False ) PostgreSQL server will receives same select  '2024-11-03 00:00:00'::timestamp at time zone 'Asia/Tehran'  at time zone 'UTC'; query from Django application, and is that appropriated select  '2024-11-03 00:00:00+03:30'::timestamptz  at time zone 'UTC'; query, straightforward and directly entering in psql terminal?

The best way to see is look at the Postgres logs and observe what is coming out of Django. You can change log_statement as shown here What to log to specify what level of statement you want to log. FYI, choosing all is alright for short periods of time, it will generate a lot of logs if left on permanently.

Try , USE_TZ = True
If we use , USE_TZ = False , django will not apply timezones.
Here , you use USE_TZ = False and set timezone as 'Asia/Tehran'

No issue about this.  I need understanding Django server-Postgresql how date time handling in this case (USE_TZ = False)
